# Can you explain to me the Bresenham's line algorithm in simple terms?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I've been trying to wrap my head around this algorithm, and I need it for my drawing function. But I can't seem to understand it.

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm gives this piece of code right at the end:

```
plotLine(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    dx = abs(x1 - x0)
    sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1
    dy = -abs(y1 - y0)
    sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1
    error = dx + dy
    
    while true
        plot(x0, y0)
        if x0 == x1 && y0 == y1 break
        e2 = 2 * error
        if e2 >= dy
            if x0 == x1 break
            error = error + dy
            x0 = x0 + sx
        end if
        if e2 <= dx
            if y0 == y1 break
            error = error + dx
            y0 = y0 + sy
        end if
    end while
```

So it starts by getting the x and y distance between the end points.
It uses sx/sy to change the computation depending on the direction.  All fine.
But then it introduces the error value, and I can't wrap my head around how it can mix apples and oranges.

I mean, I do kind of superficially understand that this value flip flops as you go along the line and determines whether the next pixel is above or below... but I just can't understand how you can mix x and y.

Secondly, I take issue with e2 and its nonclalant doubling of the error value for some reason.
And then the value is used and compared to dx and dy.

I just can't I'm too simple to understand this. I wasted a week on trying to figure this out. I have like 10 websites showing the code, but none have an explanation that would make me go: "oh, now I understand."

So please, can you explain this to me in simple terms without too much math lingo and weird function and delta notation. It's just coordinates and a line.

Thank you

Comment: You will likely get better answers at https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ for example: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/1785/18666

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function like $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - r^2$ or $g(x, y) = Ax + By - C$.  Then $f(x, y)=0$ describes a circle and $g(x, y) = 0$ describes a line.

More importantly, $f(x, y) > 0$ means you are outside of the circle, and $g(x, y) > 0$ only on exactly one side of the line.

All Bresenham algorithms work by keeping track of $f(x, y)$ in a register (in your case, it is called "error"), and simultaneously modifying $(x, f)$ or $(y, f)$ as long as $f$ remains non negative.  Here is a short derivation for drawing a line using $f(x, y) = Ay - Bx + C$ assuming $x_2 > x_1$ and $y_2 > y_1$ and $y_2 - y_1 > x_2 - x_1$.  Note that $f(x, y) > 0$ means you are above the line.

```
x = x_1
y = y_1
loop
  plot x, y
  if (x, y) = (x_2, y_2) finished
  y = y + 1
  if f(x + 1, y) >= 0
    x = x + 1
```

So instead of recalculating $f$ every time, you can do this:

```
x = x_1
y = y_1
f = A*y - B*x + C
loop
  plot x, y
  if (x, y) = (x_2, y_2) finished
  y = y + 1
  f = f + A
  if f - B >= 0
    x = x + 1
    f = f - B
```

More advanced versions can even look at the magnitude of $f(x, y)$ to choose the opacity (alpha) of a color for an aliasing effect.  You could also change the $f(x, y) \ge 0$ check to something like $|f(x, y)| \ge K$, and changing the control flow, for a fatter line.